# Get Directory Name

Tags: php

I have this script that runs through all subdirectories of the directory *images* and prints out all the images.

```
<?php
    $dirname = 'images/*/';
    $images  = glob($dirname . "*");
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" class=image /><br>';
    }
?>
```

I also want to know the name of the subdirectories (the "*" in $dirname) where each image has been taken from so I can print it out.

So in the browser it should come out like this:

- *picture from directory A*
- echo "This picture is from directory A"
- *picture from directory B*
- echo "This picture is from directory B"

Comment: Unclear. What does that code do, related to what you want it to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the directory name and then get the trailing part of that:

```
echo basename(dirname($image));
```

Comment: It worked well, but it only echo's the name of one of the directories for every directory in the loop. For example it only echoed "A" twice for both of the images (there is one image in A and B).

Comment: No, you did something wrong. Do a `var_export($images);`

Comment: Aha! Thanks! There were two pictures in directory A.